# Sum relative numbers C++

Tags: c++

There is any function to sum relative numbers? 
Example

I Have 5 and -10 So the result should be: 15
or

```
-5 (+) 15 -> 20
-1 (+) 1 -> 2
```

There is any function in C++ to sum numbers like that?

Comment: explain better, you think C++ can't handle expressions with constants?

Comment: What is the operation (+)? From your examples it seems to be the *distance* between 2 numbers

Comment: What should the result be with 2 positive numbers and with 2 negative numbers?

Comment: I don't understand how `-5 + 15 == 20` without any intervening functions.

Comment: You probably meant **absolute** numbers, not _'relative'_!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: in fact, he asked what is this function! (the abs, of course...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about such function, however you can simply create one: just add absolute values:

```
#include <iostream>

int sumAbs( int a, int b) {
    return std::abs( a) + std::abs( b);
}

int main() {
    int a = -5;
    int b = 10;
    std::cout << sumAbs( a, b); // 15
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you intend absolute values? You can use the `abs` function.

`abs(-5) + abs(15)` gives `20` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the difference? `abs(15 - (-5))` also gives 20.